# How do I properly size the ground wire for a subpanel?

Tags: subpanel

What is the general rule for sizing ground wire relative to the conductors?  I know I saw this somewhere on here, but I cannot find it.

I'm running aluminum (#1 AWG aluminum) to my subpanel and I'd rather not try to tie a #1 wire into my ground bar.  Can I use #4 Al for ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES you can use #4 Al as your ground.  Your 1AWG Al is good for a 100 AMP feeder (actually 110).  From NEC 250.122 this requires an #8 CU or #6 Al ground wire as a minimum (or 6CU and 4 Al if you are really running a 110Amp Feeder).

As a reminder, your feeder will be 4 wires, the two hots and the neutral will be #1AL (unless you've de-rated the neutral to 70% or from specific load balancing calculations if that is allowed in your area).

> NEC 250.122 table:[image]

Comment: Thanks mark.  Yes, the question regards the ground running with the conductors (i.e. ***not*** to ground bars) to connect my subpanel's ground back to the main panel.  That being said, is there a general rule for sizing the ground?  That's what I was getting to.

Comment: If it were true that #1Al is good for 110A, then you would need to upsize the ground wire in proportion also.  However, #1Al is in fact only good for 100A (can't use the 90C column).

Answer (score 0):

If your question is not related to Feeders, but instead about what size wire to run from your ground bus-bar to your earth ground (copper rod or old plumbing tie in) than the answer is NO;   AL is not to be used when within 18" of the ground/earth.

> NEC250.92: Where used outside, aluminum or copper-clad aluminum grounding conductors shall not be installed within 18 in. (457 mm) of the earth.

(Thanks @Ecnerwal for the corrections!)

Comment: At least two problems with this answer: UFER (Concrete Encased Electrode) is #4AWG copper (it's one of those *"other types of electrodes that require..."*) and you can't use Aluminum for ground connectons in the ground (or within 18" of the ground, meaning dirt, in this case) "Insulated or bare aluminum or copper-clad aluminum grounding conductors shall not be used where in direct contact with masonry or the earth or where subject to corrosive conditions.
Where used outside, aluminum or copper-clad aluminum grounding conductors shall not be installed within 18 in. (457 mm) of the earth."

Comment: i'm editing this answer so that it doesn't include my original BAD information.  thanks @Ecnerwal.  Also, I suspect his real question was about wire size to run in the four wire feeder for the ground.

Comment: When quoting, it's _very_ helpful to use quote formatting. Click the [edit] button to see how I did it so you can do so too.

Comment: It's allowable for a ground feeder provided the ground wire is insulated the whole way (except under the lugs themselves obviously :)   Bare aluminum is NOT allowed in wet/dirt locations.  It is also not allowed in the Grounding Electrode System.